# Finding the longest string name and length

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write a program that allows me to find the longest string name after input. So far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    int tot[20];
    int len; /*length of string*/
    char nam[20]; /*the variable the user will be entering*/
    char nnam[20]; /*new name variable.
                   where the longest is kept*/

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){ /*user input of 6 strings*/
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", nam);

        len = strcmp(nnam, nam); /*comparing length of input 
                                 to stored string*/

        if (len > 0){ /*condition*/
            strcpy(nnam, nam); /*should copy the largest
                               value into nnam*/
        }
    }

    printf("The longest string is: %s\n", nnam);
    printf("The string length is: %d\n", strlen(nnam));

    return 0;
}
```

This seemed to work for example:

```
FIRST OUTPUT:
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: purple
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: red
The longest string is: purple
The string length is: 6
```

But then this happened:

```
SECOND OUTPUT:
Enter a string: blue
Enter a string: black
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: purple
Enter a string: gold
Enter a string: green
The longest string is: black
The string length is: 5
```

And this:

```
THIRD OUTPUT:
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: purple
Enter a string: gold
Enter a string: red
Enter a string: red
The longest string is: gold
The string length is: 4
```

Not sure what's happened here. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you expect `len = strcmp(nnam, nam);` would give you a comparison of the string lengths?

Comment: I thought it would because I thought the strcmp function would already have been looking at the difference in string length. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: I rolled back your "Fixed" edit. "Fixing" questions, and adding "Solved" to yheir title defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow as a *question and answer* repository. As a new member, you may not be aware of this; please take the [Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). If none of the existing answers helped, you can add an answer yourself.

Comment: Alright, was confused a bit why it was changed but understand why now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare their length not the strings themselves:

```
scanf("%s", nam);

if (strlen(nam) > strlen(nnam)){
    strcpy(nnam, nam);
}
```

Comment: What makes this different to what I wrote?

Comment: So is there a reason to why I was getting those results earlier?

Comment: first, strcmp compare the strings alphabetically, not their lenghts, and second, when `i = 0` you were comparing nnam (which wasn't even defined at that moment) with nam.